# Find with preg_match all float numbers in text

Tags: preg-match

with preg mach i need find all float numbers (x.xx).

```
preg_match_all('/\d+.\d{1,2}/', $test, $list);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
```

Now my preg_match find all numbers, but i need only float. How fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the '.' needs to be escaped..

a '.' means any character.. but you are searching for a literal '.' so you should write
.

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d{1,2}/', $test, $list);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
```